# Updating child records using bulk API

Tags: rest-api, bulk-api, create-records, bulk

Can we create the child record of a parent object using the Bulk API. I am trying to use the bulk API and I want to create all the child record of a parent record. Is it possible through using bulk API? I just want to create the child record. I would like to do it in one request and mention all the childs when using the bulk api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the bulk api is only able to work with a single object at a time.

You can, however, do this with the [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_create.htm#MixedSaveSection).

> You can create records for multiple object types, including custom
>   objects, in one call with API version 20.0 and later. For example, you
>   could create a contact and an account in one call. You can create
>   records for up to 10 object types in one call.
>
> Records are saved in the same order that they are entered in the
>   sObjects input array. If you are entering new records that have a
>   parent-child relationship, the parent record must precede the child
>   record in the sObjects array. For example, if you are creating a
>   contact that references an account that is also being created in the
>   same call, the account must have a smaller index in the sObjects array
>   than the contact does. The contact references the account by using an
>   External ID field.

Edit:

Even though you can't do this in one call with the bulk API, if you have an external Id on the parent object you can use that to specify the parent for a child record in a subsequent call.

So you would create the parent records first, and then do another upload to create the child records and supplying the external id for the parent to link them.

There are details on that in the [bulk API docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_csv_rel_field_header_row.htm).

If you have a field on the parent object called ExtId__c, you can specify that in the child update as ParentObject__r.ExtId__c and the bulk api will associate them.

Comment: Can work with Millions of data with this?

Comment: No, you can only create 200 records with a single call.

Comment: I just added an alternative that might work with the bulk api. A single call won't work but this will get you close.

Comment: Thank you ! I do not know which object are child but I know there is common field API name they all share. Can I update that field in all the childs of a parent without knowing the child object API name ?

Comment: No, you need to know which objects you're creating in advance - that means knowing the API names of the parent and child objects and the API names for all of the fields that need to be updated.

Comment: Can I use REST API similar to Bulk API to update/create the child record using external Id of the parent record? Or does REST API works differently?

Comment: You can use the REST API to create parent and child records using Composite calls: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_create.htm.

Comment: Thanks. I read that we can create one level hierarchy meaning account and it's contact. Can I create 3-4 level down like what if contact have a relationship with another object , can we create that as well?

Comment: The limit is 25 subrequests. So you should be able to create an account, contact, and 3-4 other related objects with one call to the REST API.

Comment: Is it possible to update the records which are in a hierarchy - Like can update the records(Account and its contact) by passing an external id from another system. THe account and contact details will be sent from A org to B org. A Org is going to update record in Org B. Can it be done using this approach?